# What does Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code and I am not sure why I am getting this statement then when I add the `;` it gives me this:

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 1, file "Code").

I did this exact code in regular Excel macros and it works fine. Here is my full function.

```vb
Function ;ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    If SUM = True Then
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
            End If
        Next rCell
    Else
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

   ColorFunction = vResult
End Function

Sub ColorFuction()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you are writing javascript code?

Comment: I'm sure he's not writing JavaScript code.

Comment: Dim was in VBScript if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes it was vb script. I dont know why it has java. I thought I put vb script.

Comment: whats up with that `;` in the function declaration?

Comment: @KevinHoffman Your code is VBA, not VBScript. Those languages are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264773.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Use the following rules when you name procedures, constants, variables, and arguments in a Visual Basic module:
>
> - **You must use a letter as the first character.**
> - You can't use a space, period (.), exclamation mark (!), or the characters @, &, $, # in the name.
> - Name can't exceed 255 characters in length.
> - Generally, you shouldn't use any names that are the same as the functions, statements, and methods in Visual Basic. You end up shadowing the same keywords in the language. To use an intrinsic language function, statement, or method that conflicts with an assigned name, you must explicitly identify it. Precede the intrinsic function, statement, or method name with the name of the associated type library. For example, if you have a variable called Left , you can only invoke the Left function using VBA.Left .
> - You can't repeat names within the same level of scope. For example, you can't declare two variables named age within the same procedure. However, you can declare a private variable named age and a procedure-level variable named age within the same module.

Using a semicolon as the first character in a function name is not valid (technically it's not a valid character anywhere in a function name).

You also can't have two functions with the same name in the same module.

Remove the semicolon from the function name, and remove the second (empty) function definiton.